# loader is not working correctly with AsyncTask(for http get request)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am new in Java, Android development and Here is my problem.
My functions in AsyncTask class

```
public class MyHttpGet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context context;

public MyHttpGet (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

protected String doInBackground(String... website) {
    // my http get code here
    return data;
}
}
```

and the problem is that I am seeing loader only one moment before receiving the data and disappearing. (My request is taking more then 5 seconds).

Answer (score -1):

Check your permissions in AndroidMainifest.xml. This line would need to be added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: if you read my question carefully, I didn't say that my code is not working, the problem is in loader :)